# Stop Scrapy crawler from external domains

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and trying to run a crawler on a few websites where my allowed domain and start url looks like this

```
 allowed_domains = ['www.siemens.com']

start_urls= ['https://www.siemens.com/']
```

The problem is that the website also contains links to different domains like

> "siemens.fr" and "seimens.de"

and I don't want the scrapy to also scrape these websites. Any suggestion on how to tell the spider not to crawl these websites.
I am trying to build a more general spider so that it is applicable to other websites also

**Update#2**

As suggested by Felix Eklöf, I tried to adjust my code and change some settings. This is what the code looks like now

**The spider**

```
class webSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'web'
    allowed_domains = ['eaton.com']

    start_urls= ['https://www.eaton.com/us/']


    # include_patterns = ['']
    exclude_patterns = ['.*\.(css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)']
    #proxies = 'proxies.txt'
    response_type_whitelist = ['text/html']
    # response_type_blacklist = []
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (allowed_domains)), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
```

And the settings look like this:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'smartspider.middlewares.SmartspiderSpiderMiddleware': 543,
    #'scrapy_testmaster.TestMasterMiddleware': 950
}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'smartspider.middlewares.SmartspiderDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'smartspider.middlewares.FilterResponses': 543,
    'smartspider.middlewares.RandomProxyForReDirectedUrls': 650,
     "scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware": 543
}
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'smartspider.pipelines.SmartspiderPipeline': 300,
}
```

Please let me know if any of these settings are interfering with the spider only accessing the internal links and maintaining the given domain

**Update3#**
As suggested by @Felix, I updated the Spider which looks like this now

```
class WebSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'web'
    allowed_domains = ['eaton.com']
    start_urls= ['https://www.eaton.com/us/']
    # include_patterns = ['']
    exclude_patterns = ['.*\.(css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)']
    
    response_type_whitelist = ['text/html']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
```

The settings look

```
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'smartspider.middlewares.SmartspiderSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    # 'smartspider.middlewares.SmartspiderDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'smartspider.middlewares.FilterResponses': 543,
    'smartspider.middlewares.RandomProxyForReDirectedUrls': 650,
}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'smartspider.pipelines.SmartspiderPipeline': 300,
#}
```

But the spider is still scraping through different domains.

But the logs are showing that it is rejecting offsite websites with another website (thalia.de)

```
2021-01-04 19:46:42 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.rtbhouse.com': <GET https://www.rtbhouse.com/privacy-center/>
2021-01-04 19:46:42 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.quicklizard.com': <GET https://www.quicklizard.com/terms-of-service/>
2021-01-04 19:46:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.thalia.de/shop/hilfe-gutschein/show/> (referer: https://www.thalia.de/)
2021-01-04 19:46:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.thalia.de/shop/hilfe-kaufen/show/> (referer: https://www.thalia.de/)
2021-01-04 19:46:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.thalia.de/shop/home/login/login/?source=%2Fde.buch.shop%2Fshop%2F2%2Fhome%2Fkundenbewertung%2Fschreiben%3Fartikel%3D149426569&jumpId=2610518> (referer: https://www.thalia.de/shop/home/artikeldetails/ID149426569.html)
2021-01-04 19:46:43 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 453 pages (at 223 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-01-04 19:46:43 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 2): https://www.thalia.de/shop/home/show/
```

Is the spider working as expected or the problem is with a specific website?

Comment: Why don't you filter URLs including "siemens.com" and ignore others.

Comment: @ibilgen I tried that but it still goes to all external links and other languages. I am trying to find a method that is applicable to any website I give in a list and  not worry about it scraping different websites. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "www." from `allowed_domains`.

Accoring to the Scrapy docs you should do it like this:

> Let’s say your target url is `https://www.example.com/1.html`, then
> add `'example.com'` to the list.

So, in your case:

```
allowed_domains = ['siemens.com']

start_urls= ['https://www.siemens.com/']
```

Comment: Tried the suggested method but it is still scraping outside the domain. Any other suggestion is very welcome. Tried with another websites - ''eaton.com'. Same problem occurs

Comment: You need to have OffsiteMiddleware enabled aswell. It think this should be enabled by default. Do you have any special settings that might interfer?

Comment: I have already tried of the OffsiteMiddleware and have edited my post to include the spider and its settings. Please let me know if it can give you a clue as to why the spider is behaving this way

Comment: I noticed that you have OffsiteMiddlware under Downloader middleware, however it's a SpiderMiddleware not a Downloader. Try just removing it, since it should be registerd in spider middleware by default.

Also, check if any of the smartspider middleware are adding meta to the requests, namely "dont_filter": True. That will interfer with OffsiteMiddleware

Comment: I have tried your suggested changes but it is still scraping different domains . e,g, .eu, .fr and also some really unrelated websites like www.ceag.de . There are no meta changes like you suggested. Any other suggestions/clues are most welcome

Comment: Check my new response above this one

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, the result is same yet unfortunately. I am not sure why 'allowed_domains' is not behaving as it should as given in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Please have a closer look at the other, country-specific domains, such as siemens.de, siemens.dk, siemens.fr, etc.

If you run a curl call against the German site, `curl --head https://www.siemens.de`, you will realize a 301 status code.

The URL is redirected to https://new.siemens.com/**de**/de.html.

THe same pattern is observed for the other countries. The ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code is embedded in the URL. If you need to filter, here is the location to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I took a closer look at your code and might have found the issue.

I belive the issue is on this line:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (allowed_domains)), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
```

The class LinkExtractor expects the argument `allow` to be a `str` or `list` of `str's`, however the str's are also expected to be regular expressions. And since you have a `.` (dot) in the url, the regular expression will interpret that as any character.

Instead you can just use the arguement `allow_domains`. Like this.

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains = allowed_domains), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
```

But, these requests should still be filtered out by the allowed_domains. So I'm not sure why that's not working, but try this.

Comment: I tried the changes that you suggested but it is still scraping different websites. Any other code do you need for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really figure out what's wrong, but I made a test project of my own. It's a totally clean project, only changed `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in settings.py.

I noticed that your spider class is extending `scrapy.Spider` but uses `rules`, I believe that class variable is only used by the generic spider `CrawlSpider`.

Here's my testSpider.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'web'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.stackoverflow.com/']
    rules = [Rule(link_extractor=LinkExtractor(), follow=True)]
```

And it seems to work fine

```
2021-01-04 12:50:13 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-01-04 12:50:13 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://stackoverflow.com/> from <GET https://www.stackoverflow.com/>
2021-01-04 12:50:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stackoverflow.com/> (referer: None)
2021-01-04 12:50:13 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'stackexchange.com': <GET https://stackexchange.com/sites>
2021-01-04 12:50:13 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'stackoverflow.blog': <GET https://stackoverflow.blog>
2021-01-04 12:50:13 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://stackoverflow.com/#for-developers> - no more 
duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2021-01-04 12:50:14 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.g2.com': <GET https://www.g2.com/products/stack-overflow-for-teams/>
2021-01-04 12:50:14 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'stackoverflowbusiness.com': <GET https://stackoverflowbusiness.com>
2021-01-04 12:50:14 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'serverfault.com': <GET https://serverfault.com>
```

So I would try using the CrawlSpider. Also, if it doesn't work you can post the whole code for the spider then I can debug it.